# Resistance through Tinned Copper

Tags: electrical-resistance, conductors

Too many conflicting articles from prominent electrical manufacturers; some state Tin solder on copper improves conductivity, some state it reduces conductivity at the expensive of corrosion resistance, and others state tinning does not affect its conductivity.

I'm perplexed. If I tin a copper wire and plug the fully tinned wire into a lug terminal, butt connector, etc. Is the tin now not in series with the circuit? Current must pass from the copper through the tin coating to the connected surface. In a high current carrying line; being that its a thin layer of tin with a fraction of the conductivity of copper, whats keeping the tin from superheating akin to placing a thin steel washer in between two copper lines? I've been doing circuit diagram simulations and coming up with similar results, so what am I doing wrong in attempting to calculate voltage drop loss/resistance expense of tinning vs gaining a highly corrosion resistant coating?

Comment: I think you're more likely to get an answer on the [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/). This seems the sort of thing they'd think about all the time.

Comment: You may have to look at the contact resistance rather than the bulk one. The contact resistance  between copper and tin may be better than between copper and copper. Counting the oxide/carbonate layer on copper pieces. At low current it may be insignificant though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tin oxide is less of a barrier to conduction and solder wetting than copper oxide is, so tin plating is common on connector pins and component leads. Tin itself has a higher *bulk* resistivity than copper. If the plating thickness is less than the [skin depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect), this has little effect, but bare copper is better at higher frequencies.